# characters min length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to make the JavaScript have a min length on the username characters. The username has to have at least 5 characters in the name. So far, I can type in the username but, still get the message we need 5 characters even if we have more or less, the only time that does not happen is when I don't type anything in. I don't quite understand why.

```
   // version 1
    let y = document.querySelector("#nick2").value;    { 
            if(y== 0)
            for(y.length=0; y.length>5; y.length++); 
 {
    console.log("need at least 5 letters in the username ");
}



//Version 2
let y = document.querySelector("#nick2").value;    { 
            if(y== 0)
           if(y.value.length !=5){
                 y.value="";
                 input=y.value
                  if(input.length<5){
                      console.log("need at least 5 letters in the username");
                    } 
                }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is your JavaScript triggered? Do you have an `onchange` attribute set? Do you have a `element.addEventListener("change", ... )` registered? Could you show the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: You have a `;` after your `for` loop for one thing, but it would really help if you aligned and formatted your code properly.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here, to be honest. Why are you doing `if(y== 0)`? `y` is presumably a string, so it will never equal 0 unless that's what they entered for their nickname. In the first one, I'm not sure what the for loop is supposed to be doing, but it's never going to do it because 0 isn't greater than 5. In the second one, strings don't have a `value` property so none of that code makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the length of your `input` element by calling a function within your `input` element's `onkeyup` method.

Something like this:

```js
function check(item) {
    let y = item.value.trim();   // trim() removes any extra whitespace

    if(y.length < 5) {
        console.log("Need at least 5 letters in username");
    } else {
        console.log("You've entered 5 or more characters for username");
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- You can pass the element as 'this' to the function -->
<input type="text" value="" onkeyup="check(this)" />
```

Note: If you want to allow whitespace characters (spaces) to be a valid input then remove `trim()`.

Comment: Maybe also add an else-statement with a "success" `console.log`. Currently the previous `console.log`s linger, which might confuse OP.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Added an `else`, thanks. Feel free to edit if there is something you'd like to add.

Comment: @3limin4t0r What is now catching my eye is the substring *username*. I think I'll add one more input element and give them ids like `id="username"` and `id="password"`, so that we can use those as the substring.

Comment: I personally wouldn't over-complicate the answer since the question is already pretty vague. Introducing more complexity might confuse OP. When I look at the question code I would assume that OP is a beginning programmer, with no or limited prior coding knowledge. If you want to improve the answer I suggest talking about some of the things going wrong in the question code.

Comment: @3limin4t0r You're right. I'll add some more basic explanation and maybe remove the last example.

Comment: @3limin4t0r That should be better now.